# concatenating regex pattern in C#

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I have a C# project that requires me to capture a string value from a html stream.

The pattern I need to match is:

```
XXXX-abc
```

Where:

```
XXXX = a 4 character integer
```

followed by a -

```
abc =  a 3 character alphanumeric.
```

I looked at `txt2re.com` and got

```
  string re1="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 1  
  string re2="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 2
  string re3="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 3
  string re4="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 4
  string re5="(-)"; // Any Single Character 1
  string re6="((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))";    // Alphanum 1
```

The thing I am having difficulty with is combining it into one expression instead of 6.
I know I can do:

```
Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

However, my OCD cringes at this method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expresion `\d{4}-\w{3}` 4 digits follow by - follow by 3 alphanumerical characters. [Here](http://regexhero.net/) is a good site to test and learn about the regular expresion.